# In Python are Lists, Tuples, and Dictionaries Data Types? Or Data Structures?

Tags: python, list, types, structure

I'm a bit confused as to what lists, tuples and dictionaries are classified as in python. I understand that int and string are examples of primitive data types in the language but I am not sure what lists, tuples and dictionaries are. Are they data structures?

Comment: The concepts aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: Python doesn't really use a language level concept of "data structures" or "data types". It has types (and in Python 3, the concept is completely merged with/synonymous with classes), but you'd need to give your definition of "data types" and "data structures" to say. I suspect the answer is "they're all both".

Comment: And for the record, `int` and `string` are no more "primitive" than `list`/`tuple`/`dict`, except insofar as they can't reference other objects. Python doesn't have low level primitive types, it has objects. Everything is an object. Even `int` is referencing a wrapper object stored elsewhere in memory (which can be referenced from multiple places).

Comment: Both. I know it can be somewhat confusing coming over from c++ for instance.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that lists, tuples, and dictionaries are data structures.

A data structure is essentially a container that can hold different data *types* (eg int, float) and on its own has a set of operating primitives that have different properties than data types. The line between types and structures is a bit blurred though- for example, strings can be understood as both.